# How can I delete my serverfault profile?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Is there anyway I can delete my server fault profile and it shouldn't effect my profile on SO.

Comment: I answered this for you in chat: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete/request a deletion by following the procedure outlined in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) on mSO.